# Serial communication breaks in WinXP compatibility mode

Tags: c++, serial-port, backwards-compatibility

I'm trying to communicate with some equipment using c++:

- Equipment 'X': Uses an API that requires WinXP
- Equipment 'Y': Communicates through serial communication

For security reasons we are not allowed to use WinXP so we're using Win7.

The serial communication with 'Y' works fine if I run the application as is. I am also able to connect to 'X' if I run the application in "Windows XP compatibility mode" (specifically the 'AdditiveRunAsHighest' flag).

The problem is that the compatibility mode seems to break the serial communication. I can still open the port and send commands but the message just bounces back. I have tried using both the CreateFileA() and CreateFileW() functions but the result is the same.

Do you have any idea if there's a way to fix this?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: Added code for the serial communication. I omitted error handling for readability

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE hComm = CreateFileW(L"COM5", // or CreateFileA("COM5",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, //Read/Write
    0,               // No Sharing
    NULL,            // No Security
    OPEN_EXISTING,   // Open existing port only
    0,               // Non Overlapped I/O
    NULL);


// Get current state
DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 }; // Initialize DCB structure
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

bool isReadCurrentCommState = GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);


// New settings
dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_57600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
dcbSerialParams.fOutxCtsFlow = false; // software flow control
dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE; // software flow control
dcbSerialParams.fOutX = true; // software flow control
dcbSerialParams.fInX = true; // software flow control

bool isSetCommState = SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);

// Timeouts
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 300;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 300;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 300;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

bool isSetCommTimeouts = SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts);

// Write something to serial port
char lpBuffer[] = "command\r\n";
DWORD dNoOFBytestoWrite;         // No of bytes to write into the port
DWORD dNoOfBytesWritten = 0;     // No of bytes written to the port
dNoOFBytestoWrite = sizeof(lpBuffer);

bool writeStatus = WriteFile(hComm,      // Handle to the Serial port
    lpBuffer,     // Data to be written to the port
    dNoOFBytestoWrite,  //No of bytes to write
    &dNoOfBytesWritten, //Bytes written
    NULL);
```

Everything returns true both with and without the compatibility mode, but the equipment only receives the command when I'm not using compatibility mode.

Edit 2: Solved!
I restarted everything again and now it works. I did try to restart before so not sure why it worked this time but thank you all for your comments.

Comment: There are far too many possibilities to list here. Can you narrow down the problem with a [mcve]?

Comment: Have you tried running the process in Win7 as an elevated administrator, with no compatibility flags?

Comment: @user4581301 I updated my post with the code for the serial communication.

Comment: @BenVoigt The effect is the same as when I run it in compatibility mode, the serial communication breaks but I can communicate with 'X'.

Comment: @JakobL: There is nothing about a Windows 7 serial port that would work for an unelevated user but then fail for an elevated administrator.  Check your test environment again, you probably have the port open in another program, or a mouse driver has claimed the port due to serial enumeration.  Or perhaps you persisted the compatibility option so it is still in effect.  Or your device is in some weird mode where it doesn't respond as you expect (a power cycle may help)